# Route works in application, fails in Cucumber test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, cucumber

I have a route that works (recognized, can follow it) in a Rails 3 application, but fails in the Cucumber test:

routes.rb:

```
resources :tests do
  member do
    post 'start'
  end
end
```

Working link in application:

```
=button_to 'Start', start_test_path(@test)
```

Gherkin step:

```
And I am on the test start page for "Sample Test"
```

Failing in paths.rb

```
when /the test start page for "([^\"]*)"/
  start_test_path(Test.find_by_name($1))

...

(::) failed steps (::)

No route matches "/tests/1/start" (ActionController::RoutingError)
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:30:in `/^(?:|I )am on (.+)$/'
features/test_workflow.feature:24:in `And I am on the test start page for "Sample Test"'
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that 'start' is a `post` action, not a `get` action. When you use the `I am on the ...` cucumber step you are generating a get request, not a post request. To fix this, simply press the button in Cucumber, instead of visiting the direct path. This can be done with the `press` cucumber step, like this:

```
When I press "Start"
```

This step will generate the appropriate post request, but it must be called after you visit the page that the button is located on. Alternatively, you can generate a post request in a custom cucumber step by doing something like this:

```
When /^I am on the test start page$/ do
  post("/tests/1/start")
end
```

Comment: Thought this solved it, but I get "wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) (ArgumentError)" for the visit method

Comment: I updated it to use the post method instead. Give that a shot.

Comment: But you're on the right track with visit not accepting post requests.  Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084212/how-do-you-post-to-a-url-in-cabybara

Comment: This is looking like a good clue that I need to revisit my workflow.  I went off the rails

Answer (score 1):

I don't know cucumber, but try this:

Rename your route from `test` to `tests` and your controller from `TestController` to `TestsController`

This just might be a case where your naming conventions are messing things up, because they are not what Rails expects.

I don't know if I am right - just a guess.

Comment: Good suggestion, but unfortunately I just copied the route incorrectly from routes.rb.  Its 'tests' in there as well