# rspec/capybara: how to simulate incoming POST requests? (rack-test won't work)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, capybara, cloudmailin

I need to receive incoming emails as multipart-formdata via a POST request from Cloudmailin.  The POST resembles the following:

```
Parameters: {"to"=>"<email@exmaple.comt>", "from"=>"whomever@example", "subject"=>"my awesome subject line....
```

Actually, receiving and parsing emails is super easy because the email is just posted as params:  params[:to], params[:from], etc.  However, how do I simulate this POST request in rails?

I built a dummy rails app to test out Cloudmailin, so I have an actual request.  However, it's a 6k character file, so I'd like to load this file as the parameters of the POST request.  I've tried using the built rails post and post_via_redirect methods to load a file, but it escapes all of the parameters( \"to\"), which is no good.  Any ideas?

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/276-testing-time-web-requests and particularly https://github.com/chrisk/fakeweb

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  I believe fakeweb was meant to test fetching from external API's.  I need to test an incoming request.  Actually, that's not true.  I just need to post some params to a controller, and the rest of the test will ensure that a proper Mail was created.

Comment: sorry, Probably I should sleep :)

Comment: Happened to see this one as a "related question", so linking it up – it fits well here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24353475/6962

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, I ended up doing:

```
@parameters = { "x_to_header"=>"<#{ @detail.info }>",
                "to"=>"<#{ @account.slug }@cloudmailin.net>",
                "from"=>"#{ @member.email }",
                "subject"=>"meeting on Monday",
                "plain"=>"here is my message\nand this is a new line\n\n\nand two new lines\n\n\n\nand a third new line"
              }
```

then just:

```
post "/where_ever", @parameters
```

seems to get the job done for now

Comment: Sounds like a neat yet simple idea

Comment: Will this work with other functions ('get' for example)?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would probably to execute a script in capybara. Just make sure with the `@javascript` tag, then load any page in your app that has jQuery installed (technically, you don't need this, but it's much easier. Then:

```
When /^I get a post request from Cloudmailin$/ do
  visit '/some/page/with/jquery'
  page.execute_script(%{$.post("/some/path?to=some_email&etc=etc");})
end
```

There's the simple `post` capybara method too, but I'm not too sure about how that works. Might be worth looking into.

Comment: Thank you Ramon for the suggestion.  However, I'm just manually building up a parameters hash then posting it API endpoint:  post '/incoming', @parameters (I guess that's the simplest possible solution for now)

Comment: So you're using capybara's post method?

Comment: I think it's just a rails thin?

Comment: Right. That `post` method is not part of Capybara. See also http://elabs.se/blog/34-capybara-and-testing-apis

Answer (score 0):

I saw this answer last night when I was updating some of my own test code for Rails 3.2.8, and which uses the Mail gem, and thought I'd share what I found.  The test code is for an application that needs to take a POST from Cloudmailin and then process it to create a new user with Devise, and then send a confirmation to that user, which the user can then follow to choose a password.  Here is my controller spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ThankyouByEmailController do

  message1 = Mail.new do 

    from "Frommy McFromerton <frommy.mcfrommerton@gmail.com>"
    to "toey.receivesalot@gmail.com"
    subject "cloudmailin test"
    body 'something'

    text_part do
      body 'Here is the attachment you wanted'
    end

    html_part do
      content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
      body '<h1>Funky Title</h1><p>Here is the attachment you wanted</p>'
    end
  end

  describe "creating new users" do

    describe "unregistered FROM sender and Unregistered TO receiver" do

      it "should create 2 new users" do
        lambda do
          post :create, :message => "#{@message1}"
        end.should change(User, :count).by(2)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Hope this clean up your own tests.  And for anyone else interested in testing the mail gem, mikel's documentation has come a long way for same:

https://github.com/mikel/mail