# What to test and how to test it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, rack-test

I want to write tests for destroying objects on ruby on rails with cucumber and capybara and rack_test.

I think that I should write a scenario like:

```
When I try to delete X object
Then I should be on the index page for ...
And I should see "Object deleted successfully"
```

I don't want to test it by clicking on a link on the index page or the show/edit page because I think I should be testing something different than purely the delete action.

Also, clicking on a link means that the interface is ok, but what happens if someone send a request to delete an object he can't and the interface doesn't show the link?

Given this, I need to send a delete request in the first step and then inspect the response to that request.

I've find troubles trying to do that because when I implement the first step as `delete url` then when I try `page.should have_contain(text)` I get the error `No response yet. Request a page first. (Rack::Test::Error)`

What do you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

check out [how-do-you-post-to-a-url-in-capybara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084212/how-do-you-post-to-a-url-in-capybara) (answering another question) but there a several examples of how to use visit in a capybara test like

```
visit "item/:id/delete"
```

Comment: Ok that question seems to solve one problem. Although after I do the post request, which works perfectly, I want to check that I'm redirected to the correct path. The problem is that after the post request, the variable `last_request.url` has the url of the redirected page but `current_url` doesn't and the step to check the url use `current_url` instead of `last_request.url`. Worst, if I change it for `last_request.url` I get `undefined method `url' for #<Rack::MockResponse:0x00000006619788> (NoMethodError)`.