# Why does my Cucumber scenario that uses json_spec fail, and where is last_json defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, rspec, cucumber

It is a very newbie question: I am developing a REST API using Rails and I'd like to use [json_spec](https://github.com/collectiveidea/json_spec) to handle JSON in RSpec and Cucumber.
I created my feature test (from [here](http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2011/07/12/test-your-api-with-cucumber-and-json_spec/)):

```
  Feature: User API
  Scenario: User list
  Given I post to "/users.json" with:
    """
    {
      "first_name": "Steve",
      "last_name": "Richert"
    }
    """
  And I keep the JSON response at "id" as "USER_ID"
  When I get "/users.json"
  Then the JSON response should have 1 user
  And the JSON response at "0" should be:
    """
    {
      "id": %{USER_ID},
      "first_name": "Steve",
      "last_name": "Richert"
    }
    """
```

But I got this error:

```
Given(/^I post to "(.*?)" with:$/) do |arg1, string|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end

When(/^I get "(.*?)"$/) do |arg1|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

I think methods **get** and **post** are provided by [capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara), but I cannot make the system recognize them.

I also read that I’ll need to define a **last_json** method but I don't know where I should add it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the blog post you cited](http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2011/07/12/test-your-api-with-cucumber-and-json_spec/) says, you need to write the "I post" and "I get" steps.

The `get` and `post` methods available in Cucumber steps are provided by rack-test, which Capybara depends on. [Capybara is not designed to POST programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084212/how-do-you-post-to-a-url-in-capybara), so I would write those steps using the rack-test methods:

```
When /^I get "(.*?)"$/ do |path|
  get path
end

Given /^I post to "(.*?)" with:$/ do |path, body|
  post path, body
end
```

Define `last_json` in env.rb, or in another .rb file in features/support. If you use rack-test, `last_json` will need to use rack-test too:

```
def last_json
  last_response.body`enter code here`
end
```