# POST request with Capybara/Cucumber and Rack/Test

Tags: ruby, rest, cucumber, capybara, rack-test

I have the same problem as follows:

In "support/env.rb":

```
module CapybaraApp
  def app; Capybara.app; end
end
World(CapybaraApp)
World(Rack::Test::Methods)
```

In "step_definitions/restUtils.rb":

```
Quando /^Send POST request to "([^\"]*)" with:$/ do |url, body|
  header 'Accept', 'application/json'
  header 'Content-Type', 'application/json'
  post url, body
end
```

Result: *undefined method 'call' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)*

Obs.: 
ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13) [x64-mingw32]
Cucumber 2.0.2

@Elye, can you help me? What are the alternatives to tests using REST? Regards!

Comment: Have you looked at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084212/how-do-you-post-to-a-url-in-capybara ?

Comment: I left the test Rack/Test and change to Unirest (http://unirest.io/ruby.html)

Comment: Jarod Adair, Thank you!