# How can I add request methods to feature specs in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a simple test feature called `test_feature_spec.rb`:

*(this is just for getting to the point of this SO question... the actual specs are much longer, actual feature specs)*

```
require "features_helper"

RSpec.feature "Simple Feature", type: :feature do
  scenario "a test scenario" do
    get "/"
  end
end
```

I can do various Rails-y things, including capybara-driven things (like `visit such_n_such_path`). However the above crashes:

```
Failures:

  1) Simple Feature a test scenario
     Failure/Error: get "/"

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `get' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::SimpleFeature:0x000000011a799788>
       Did you mean?  gets
                      gem
```

If I simply change it from `type: :feature` to `type: :request` it works just fine:

```
> rspec spec/features/test_feature_spec.rb
.

Finished in 0.64913 seconds (files took 5.82 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

It seems that with `type` => `request` Rails or Rspec loads some stuff to allow calling controller routes, but it doesn't with `type` => `feature`.

**Is there a way to load those helper methods (like `get` and `post` and such) but still leave the feature as `type: :feature`?**

I know I could just change it to `type: :request` but *technically* these are feature specs, even though for some of them, to set up some state or do whatever, they need to call certain URLs.

Comment: It has been a while since I used Capybara, but I believe that you should use `visit` instead of `get` when using paths - can you try that? `get` is usually used with `:new` etc

Comment: `visit` worked, but my problem is that I want to be able to do direct HTTP calls of GET or POST (or whatever) type. `visit` is for driving an end-user browser like interaction. Anyway, I figured out an easy fix (see my answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is a solution for this that works:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24353475/1218280

The reason I asked this is a bit odd. I'm currently refactoring some Cucumber tests to be Rspec feature specs. Some of them were making `get` or `post` commands to endpoints in our app as "setup" steps. For example, there is an endpoint for enabling a certain flag in a DB record. I could just set up the DB object with the flag set, but I wanted to stay true to the original Cucumber code as much as possible (at least at first).

So now I can do this (and it works):

```
require "features_helper"

RSpec.feature "Simple Feature", type: :feature do
  scenario "a test scenario" do
    session = ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.new(Rails.application)
    response = session.get("/")
    # or I could do: session.post("/api/xyz", params: { one: "one", two: "two" })
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `spec_helper` you can try with:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FeaturesHelper, :type => :request
end
```

Comment: I'd want it the other way... i.e. adding RequestHelper to type :feature. I'll try it out, though